# Detail of Provider with Azure active directory token

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services

I have used google and microsoft account for azure active directory authentication. After authenticate from AAD it return access token. That we are passing in request header. On bases of token i want to get the detail of current provider. Is this possible to get the detail of user in web api code with help of token that i am passing in header?

Comment: What kind of access token is this?

Comment: With WS-Federation, I'm able to to obtain the identity provider from the SAML token's claim set. The claim type is called 'idp'.

Comment: i have used this piece of code in xamarin forms,   var user = await DependencyService.Get<IAuthentication>().LoginAsync(azureService.MobileService, provider);
I am getting token in  "MobileServiceAuthencticationToken"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all sorts of information from the `/.auth/me` endpoint.  Since you are using Azure Mobile Apps with Xamarin Forms:

Set up a model for the claims:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TaskList.Models
{
    public class AppServiceIdentity
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id_token")]
        public string IdToken { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "provider_name")]
        public string ProviderName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user_id")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user_claims")]
        public List<UserClaim> UserClaims { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserClaim
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "typ")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "val")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then use the following to get the claims:

```
List<AppServiceIdentity> identities = null;

public async Task<AppServiceIdentity> GetIdentityAsync()
{
    if (client.CurrentUser == null || client.CurrentUser?.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Not Authenticated");
    }

    if (identities == null)
    {
        identities = await client.InvokeApiAsync<List<AppServiceIdentity>>("/.auth/me");
    }

    if (identities.Count > 0)
        return identities[0];
    return null;
}
```

The provider and provider token are in the model.  Any claims that are returned by the provider are in the `UserClaims` object, which you can use LINQ to access.  For example, to retrieve the name:

```
var identity = await service.GetIdentityAsync();
if (identity != null) {
    name = identity.UserClaims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.Equals("name")).Value;
}
```

You can get more information from the section of my book: https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/authorization/

Comment: I know that we can get the detial of user using .auth/me at client side, but i want to get the detail of user at server side , i mean i want to get the detail in web api with the help of token.

Comment: Server side is documented here:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#user-info